# Resource Controllers except not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i tried to use except (Partial Resource Routes) with resource controller to prevent any one to go to show page but it not working and give me error.

Note: i put 404.blade / 500.blade in errors folder in the views, i am using laravel 5.5

please look to blow screenshot
[image]

[image]

Comment: The syntax on the routes file looks like mine. Are you sending a GET request or is it possibly a POST/PUT request?

Comment: Your route list in the terminal window seems to show a user.show route. You make have to run php artisan route:clear

Comment: Pro i have an error look to second screen shot